# Does the MacBook Air have no RAM because it uses flash?

Tags: macbook-pro

Silly question, but does the MacBook Air not actually have RAM because it uses Flash or what?

Does it make application loading faster than the MacBook Pro?

Comment: The flash is instead of the hard disk.  Not the RAM.

Comment: Not silly one bit. RAM is something that isn't mentioned on iOS devices at all, and on Air's it's part of the standard builds and not something you can change later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every model of the Macbook Air has RAM. Every computer has some amount of RAM.

[image: Apple Store MBAir Picker]

What led you to believe it didn't have RAM?

Answer (score 5):

The RAM is soldered onto the logic board in the MacBook Air line, so it's not something you can replace as a distinct part that can be added later.

This cuts both ways - in one respect, the product is smaller, has less moving parts, and is a more standard configuration. On the other hand, you can't add more later, take advantage of replacing one small part if it fails or delay the decision how much RAM to buy since it's fixed when you select a model.